# Finding probability on operation time of batteries

Tags: probability

A lot of five identical batteries is life tested. The probability assignment is assumed to be $$ P (A )  = \int_{A} \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-x/\lambda} d x$$ for any event $ A \subseteq [0, \infty)$, where $\lambda > 0$ is a known constant. Thus the probability that a battery fails after time $t$ is given by $$ P (t, \infty) = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-x/\lambda} dx, ~~~~~ t \geq 0. $$ If the times to failure of the batteries are independent, what is the probability that at least one battery will operating after $t_0$ hours?

My approach:
$$p \rightarrow \text{proability of battery operating after $t_0$}$$
$$\text{Answer} = \binom{5}{1}p^4(1-p) + \binom{5}{2}p^3(1-p)^2 + \dotsb +\binom{5}{5}p^0(1-p)^5 $$

I am not sure whether I am correct or not. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe that is correct. You have the right idea, but you have swapped the $p$ and the $1-p$. For example, for the first term, we are looking for the chance that exactly one battery operates past time $t_0$. Well, we have denoted this chance to be $p$. The chance that is does not survive past $t_0$, is $1-p$. And so, using the binomial distribution, the chance that one battery lasts past $t_0$ is 
$$\binom{5}{1}p^1(1-p)^{5-1} = \binom{5}{1} p(1-p)^4.$$ 
The same is true for the other terms, so it is
$$\sum_{k=1}^5 \binom{5}{k} p^k(1-p)^{5-k}.$$

However, it is faster to calculate using the complement: No batteries last past $t_0$. The chance that this happens is $1-p$ for a particular battery. So this is going to be
$$1-(1-p)^5=\sum_{k=1}^5 \binom{5}{k} p^k(1-p)^{5-k}.$$

You still have to solve for $p$. It turns out to be $p = \exp(-t_0/\lambda)$.